Confused by many different definitions of antiderivative
Wikipedia:

an antiderivative ... of a function $f$ is a differentiable function $F$ whose derivative is equal to the original function $f$. This can be stated symbolically as $F' = f$.

Stewart, Strang, Herman, et al:

A function $F$ is an antiderivative of the function $f$  if  $$F'(x)=f(x)$$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$.

Tao (2022, Analysis I, 4e, p. 257):

Let $I$ be a bounded interval, and let $f : I \to \mathbf R$ be a function. We say that a function $F : I \to \mathbf R$ is an antiderivative of $f$ if $F$ is differentiable on $I$ and $F'(x) = f (x)$ for all limit points $x$ of $I$.

Velleman (2016):

Suppose $f$ is a function and $I$ is an open interval contained in the domain of $f$. We say that a function $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ on $I$ if $F$ is differentiable on $I$, and for all $x \in I$, $F′(x) = f (x)$.

ProofWiki:

Let $F$ be a real function which is continuous on the closed interval $[a..b]$ and differentiable on the open interval $(a..b)$.
Let $f$ be a real function which is continuous on the open interval $(a..b)$.
Let:
$\forall x\in(a..b):F′(x)=f(x)$
where $F′$ denotes the derivative of $F$ with respect to $x$.
Then $F$ is a primitive of $f$

I am confused by this variety of definitions.
My questions:

For a function $f$ to have an antiderivative, must its domain be an interval? An open interval (Velleman, ProofWiki)? A bounded interval (Tao)?

Must an antiderivative be differentiable (Wikipedia, Tao, Velleman)?

Why does Tao bring in limit points? (Isn't every point in an interval a limit point?)

Why does ProofWiki have the additional two endpoints in the domain of $F$ and also the requirement that $F$ be continuous there?



Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I assume there is a typo in your citation of Tao's definition.

@TedShifrin: Yes thanks, missing a prime on F

Note that, after the definition quoted above, Velleman extends the definition to intervals that are not open.  This involves an extra complication, because it requires the use of one-sided derivatives at endpoints of the interval.  See Velleman's Definitions 4.9.2-4.9.4.

In short, all of these definitions are correct. There are small differences because this is a foundational concept that appears in various ways and in various contexts, and each author presents this concept in a way that suits the local needs. This occurs throughout math, and this is one reason why it's a good idea to precisely state which definition one is using in each instance.
It's also true that mathematicians often use the exact same words to describe completely different things often in math. That's annoying, but that's the way of it.
The short answer to all of your questions is --- it might depend on the definition the authors use. More precisely:

Each author uses their own definition. Read each separately.
I think the interesting, mathematical question here is: are there any functions which have a Tao-antiderivative but don't have a Proofwiki-antiderivative (and similarly for the other pairs). Rather than focusing on particulars of definitions, this asks about the mathematical content behind them. This type of questioning is a good habit to get into!

I don't know why you point to Tao and Velleman here. Each of the five definitions you give require $F$ to be differentiable and to satisfy $F' = f$ on an appropriate region.



Isn't every point in a bounded interval $I$ a limit point of $I$?

No! For example, in the bounded, open interval $(0, 1)$, the points $0$ and $1$ are not limit points of $I$. This is analogous to the other definitions that omit the endpoints.

You'll have to ask the writers of ProofWiki. Perhaps they have in mind the simplest case of functions continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$, but which you examine only on some finite interval $[a, b]$. It probably simplifies something they describe elsewhere.



How are $0$ and $1$ not limit points of $(0,1)$? But Tao's statement makes no sense to me, since his requirement that $F'(x)=f(x)$ for a limit point $x$ certainly needs $x$ to be in the domain of $f$. Confusing.

@TedShifrin I don't have Tao's book. I assumed that he restricted to limit points of $I$ that are in $I$. I agree that this is unclear from the definition given.

I don't know why you point to Tao and Velleman here Stewart et al and ProofWiki don't require that $F$ be differentiable. (For Stewart et al, it could be that $F$ is also defined for points not in the domain of $f$ and that $F$ is not differentiable at those points. Similarly for ProofWiki. Also, for ProofWiki, $F$ is defined at the endpoints $a$ and $b$ but need not be differentiable at those points.)
